# ASP.Net Core 2.1 IdentityCore (Role Claims not being added on user sign in)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using **ASP.Net Core 2.1** with **IdentityCore Service**, the application is a pure API, no views at all. For authentication I'm purely using **Steam authentication** (No User/Pass login) provided by, https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers

This API has been created to fit a very specific authentication workflow (User's can only login to the API with Steam) the Angular SPA sitting as the frontend handles the workflow just fine.

**The problem** is that when I add a Role to a user (I've already got roles seeded and I've added my own steam account to the Admin Role), the role type claims are not being added on login, therefore when an admin user attempts to access an API route protected by [Authorize(Roles = "Admin") I'm being returned an Unauthorized Redirect.

Below I have added all code snippets I think is required (feel free to request more).

If I use (I am currently using this as a temporary solution, but it is not ideal for future development);

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RSContext>()
   .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
   .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The application correctly adds the role claims on user sign in (and the Authorize attributes work), using all existing code from AuthController.cs, yet using IdentityCore it fails. I feel I am missing a single line that is responsible for this but after trolling MSDN docs for days I am finally outwitted.

**NOTE:** The API will **correctly authenticate** and set the users cookies on sign in, but does not add the users roles to the users identity claims. Therefore, Authentication is Working, Authorization is not. If I utilise the [Authorize] attribute without specifying a Role it works flawlessly and only allows Authenticated users to access the route whilst denying unAuthenticated users. This can be seen in the Testing Screenshot at the end, identities[0].isAuthenticated = True, but the admin role is not being added to the Identity's Claims. As noted above, if I do not use AddIdentityCore and use AddIdentity, the roles are added to the user's claims correctly and the [Authorize(Role = "Admin")] attribute will work as expected, only allowing users that are apart of the Admin role to access it.

Startup.cs (Omitted irrelevant parts, eg. Database Connection)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
    {
        opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        opt.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        opt.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters += ":/";
    });

    builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
    builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<RSContext>();
    builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
    builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
    builder.AddRoles<Role>();
    builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
    builder.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>>();
    builder.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultForbidScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    })
        .AddSteam(options =>
        {
            options.ApplicationKey = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Steam:Key").Value;
            options.CallbackPath = "/api/auth/steam/callback";
            options.Events.OnAuthenticated = OnClientAuthenticated;
        })
        .AddIdentityCookies(options =>
        {
            options.ApplicationCookie.Configure(appCookie =>
            {
                appCookie.Cookie.Name = "RaidSimulator";
                appCookie.LoginPath = "/api/auth/login";
                appCookie.LogoutPath = "/api/auth/logout";
                appCookie.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                appCookie.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                appCookie.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                appCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
                appCookie.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                appCookie.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
            });
            options.ExternalCookie.Configure(extCookie =>
            {
                extCookie.Cookie.Name = "ExternalLogin";
                extCookie.LoginPath = "/api/auth/login";
                extCookie.LogoutPath = "/api/auth/logout";
                extCookie.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                extCookie.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                extCookie.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                extCookie.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    RolesSeed.Seed(roleManager).Wait();

    app.UseCors();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}

// Responsible for storing/updating steam profile in database
private async Task OnClientAuthenticated(OpenIdAuthenticatedContext context)
{
    var rsContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RSContext>();
    var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();

    var profile = context.User?.Value<JObject>(SteamAuthenticationConstants.Parameters.Response)
                        ?.Value<JArray>(SteamAuthenticationConstants.Parameters.Players)?[0]?.ToObject<SteamProfile>();

    // TODO: Handle this better, Redir user to an informative error page or something
    if (profile == null)
        return;

    var dbProfile = await rsContext.SteamProfiles.FindAsync(profile.SteamId);
    if (dbProfile != null)
    {
        rsContext.Update(dbProfile);
        dbProfile.UpdateProfile(profile);
        await rsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        await rsContext.SteamProfiles.AddAsync(profile);
        await rsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

AuthController.cs => The only code responsible for authenticating against the Identity.Application scheme

```
[HttpGet("callback")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Steam")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback([FromQuery]string ReturnUrl)
{
    ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl?.Contains("api/") == true ? "/" : ReturnUrl;

    if (HttpContext.User.Claims.Count() > 0)
    {
        var provider = HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
        var nameIdentifier = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var name = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);

        var loginResult = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(provider, nameIdentifier, false);
        if (loginResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl ?? "/api/auth/claims");
        }

        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(new User { UserName = nameIdentifier, SteamId = nameIdentifier.Split("/").Last() });
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(nameIdentifier);
            var identity = await userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, new UserLoginInfo(provider, nameIdentifier, name));

            if (identity.Succeeded)
            {
                await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(provider, nameIdentifier, false);
                return Redirect(ReturnUrl ?? "/api/auth/claims");
            }
        }
    }

    return BadRequest(new { success = false });
}

[HttpGet("claims")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetClaims()
{
    var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var claims =
        User.Claims.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Type,
            c.Value
        });

    var inAdmin = new string[] {
        "User.IsInRole(\"Admin\") = " + User.IsInRole("Admin"),
        "User.IsInRole(\"ADMIN\") = " + User.IsInRole("ADMIN"),
        "User.IsInRole(\"admin\") = " + User.IsInRole("admin"),
        "userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, \"admin\") = " + await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "admin")
    };

    return Ok(new { success = true, data = new { claims, inAdmin, User.Identities } });
}
```

RoleSeeder.cs

```
public static async Task Seed(RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
{
    // Developer Role
    if(!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Developer"))
    {
        var role = new Role("Developer");
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    }
    // Community Manager Role
    if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Community Manager"))
    {
        var role = new Role("Community Manager");
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    }
    // Admin Role
    if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin"))
    {
        var role = new Role("Admin");
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    }
    // Moderator Role
    if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Moderator"))
    {
        var role = new Role("Moderator");
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    }
}
```

Testing Screenshot:
[claims/identities/roletest API Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oarHT.png)

Comment: Did you create a JWT token??

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha
I'm not using JWT, I'm using Cookie Authentication as the Angular frontend is hosted on the same domain as the backend. (Therefore I can just send the cookie with the XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: The best way for authorization is JWT token, but if you have use of cookie, I can create a sample for you for authorization.

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha I understand this and I thank you for the offer, but I believe it is unnecessary in this current situation as this API's sole purpose is to feed the SPA (No other endpoints will ever utilise it).  
The reason I deterred from using JWT to begin with was to avoid having the API return views or the SPA have to handle popup windows to capture the Token (there's a few ways that this can be handled, but I'd prefer to use cookies with API redirecting back to the SPA on success/error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted this issue to ASP.Net Identity GitHub repo, it is a known bug and has been resolved in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Link: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1997

Answer (score 0):

You have tow way for this issue.

When you send a request to any `WebService`,  If you set, `Authorization` be run Now:

1. Before `login` If you want to send a request to your `WebService`, and want to ignore `Authorization` you have to use of `Allowanonymus` Attribute like:

   [Allowanonymous]
   Public void Login()
   {
       // here
   }

With this attribute, Authorization will ignore the request.

2. Now! If you want to send a request after `login`, you should to create you `cookie` In login time, and send a response to `client`, and also you have save that cookie in your `localStorage` in client, for Identifying in client. After this you have to set that `cookie` in 
   `header` of every request. With this way, you authorization will Don!

Now If you want, I can create a sample for Authorization in best practice.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but I don't believe this answers the problem at hand.
The problem isn't the Authentication, the authentication works flawlessly with the exception that the Users Roles are not being added to the Identity's claims. The cookie is being set correctly and API is able to correctly test whether a user is authenticated, but it is unable to Authorize a user against a Role as the users roles are not being added to the Identity Claims (even though they exist in the database). I believe this is due to the configuration of services.AddIdentityCore<>().

Comment: @Pinkstink I checked again you code, and I see that you used of JWT. You have to create claim, did you create that??

Comment: I am not using JWT, simply the Forbid and Challenge Schemes(As Noted, this will return a http error code instead of an authentication redirect), If I was to comment that out and have the schemes use their defaults, the issue is replicated. @AmirReza-Farahlagha